# Sweave doesn't seem to get .Rnw file encoding right

Tags: r, character-encoding, sweave

This question arose out of the following question on tex.sx: [Sweave generating invalid LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28710/2693). The problem seems to be that `Sweave` is not recognizing the encoding of the file, despite the locale being set to UTF-8, and the `.Rnw` file being saved as UTF-8.  The end result is that any `.Rnw` file that contains non-ASCII characters ends up producing NA in the resultant `.tex` file. As you can read in the comments to that question, another user doesn't show the problem, with what is apparently an identical setup. (R 2.13.1 on a Mac) Here's a minimal document that fails.

**Update**

Based on Aaron's suggestions, I've added `sessionInfo` to the `.Rnw` file, and now the real problem reveals itself. When `Sweave` processes the file, it seems to change the locale.

**`.Rnw` file**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Some non-ascii text: éüáî
<<>>=
sessionInfo()
@ 
\end{document}
```

Running this through `Sweave`, produces the following `.tex` file. The line containing the non-ASCII characters has been converted into `NA` by `Sweave`. It seems also that the locale has been changed:

**Resultant `.tex` file**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
NA
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> sessionInfo()
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.13.1
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}
\end{document}
```

`sessionInfo()` from within `R.app` returns:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
```

**Update (Response to Aaron)**

```
> text <- readLines("sweave-enc-test.Rnw", warn = FALSE)
> enc <- tools:::.getVignetteEncoding(text, convert = TRUE)
> 
> text
[1] "\\documentclass{article}"     "\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}" "\\begin{document}"           
[4] "Some non-ascii text: éüáî"    "\\end{document}"             
> enc
[1] "UTF-8"
> iconv(text, enc, "")
[1] "\\documentclass{article}"     "\\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}" "\\begin{document}"           
[4] "Some non-ascii text: éüáî"    "\\end{document}"
```

(This is the output from within the R console in `R.app`.)

Comment: I can see the special characters in the .tex file, but not in the pdf. 2.13.0.

Comment: @Alan, thanks. I was hoping that might duplicate the problem. Could you add sessionInfo() to the .Rnw file (see edit to my "answer")

Comment: Looks like we're closer!  How are you running Sweave?  That is from the command line, with R CMD Sweave, or from within R, with Sweave()?  Do both give the same result?

Comment: I'm running it via a TeXShop engine (essentially a bash script.) But that seems to be the problem: if I run R CMD Sweave from the command line it produces the correct output, but if I use the TeXShop bash script, *within TeXShop* it produces the incorrect output. If I use the TeXShop bash script *from the command line* it produces the correct file.  Weird.  So this is a TeXShop problem, it seems.

Comment: Starting bash on Macs is a little odd; I don't quite understand what it uses when it starts up.  In Terminal, you get the UTF8 locale by default, but in X11, you don't; you have to set it in bashrc.  Maybe TeXShop is starting bash in the same way X11 does.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks a lot for your troubleshooting on this. It has definitely narrowed down the problem.  I've posted a question to the TeX on OSX mailing list about the issue, which is clearly now related to TeXShop.

Comment: Also see a related question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23273

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Potential fix:*

Try putting

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

in your TeXShop script.

(Original idea was in the `~/.bashrc` file, but apparently TeXShop doesn't load that.)

*EARLIER:*

What happens when you put `sessionInfo()` in the Rnw file?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Some non-ascii text: éüáî
<<>>=
sessionInfo()
@ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that might duplicate the problem.  Could you add sessionInfo() to the .Rnw file (see edit to my "answer")

Comment: that seems to reveal the problem directly.  The local is clearly wrong.  (BTW, I'm using TeXShop to edit the source.)

Comment: putting export `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` into the `.bashrc` won't help, since scripts run from within TeXShop don't load it.  But putting that into the TeXShop script itself does solve the problem.  I was just about to post this as an answer, but you beat me to it. If you update your answer to say that, I'll accept it.