# Sweave bugs (?): removes document options and inserts empty lines

Tags: r, sweave

Consider a file minimal.Rnw containing

```
\documentclass[
paper=a4,% 210mm × 297mm
pagesize% write page size to dvi
]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{engine=R}
\SweaveOpts{pdf=TRUE}
Some text
\end{document}
```

When I compile it with R CMD Sweave, I obtain a .tex file which looks like this:

```
\documentclass[%
NA
pagesize% write page size to dvi
]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}


Some text
\end{document}
```

I have two questions:

1) Why is the first option to `\documentclass` replaced by `NA` and how can this be avoided?

2) I read that `\SweaveOpts` should be given after `\begin{document}` but
  apparently it creates empty lines (which correspond to new paragraphs in the
  generated .tex file). How can I prevent this from happening?

In case this matters: I work with Emacs 24 on Mac OS X 10.7.3 with R 2.14.0 and TeXLive 2011.

**UPDATE**

Concerning problem 1), I modified my call to Sweave (from Emacs) in .emacs as follows (to tell Sweave the file encoding) -- still, it creates `NA` in the line containing the non-ASCII character:

```
(add-hook 'Rnw-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
         '("Sweave" "R CMD Sweave --encoding='utf8' %s"
           TeX-run-command nil t :help "Run Sweave") t)
    (setq TeX-command-default "Sweave")))
```

Comment: Might this works `\% 210mm × 297mm`. Not tested.

Comment: According to the documentation, you can put \SweaveOpts before \begin{document} -- and that is what I always do. However, you sometimes need it after \begin{document}, for local changes: if you are already in vertical mode (i.e., between paragraphs), as in your example, the empty lines are ignored.

Comment: Thanks for helping. If I put `\SweaveOpts` before `\begin{document}`, the empty lines are inserted there. I consider this a conceptual bug, certainly not too important, though. With 1) I still don't know. What frightens me is that I don't know what other parts I don't know will be automatically replaced by Sweave. That's certainly more dangerous

Comment: I can not reproduce (Emacs 34, Win 7-64, R 2.14.1, MiKTeX) the NA subs. Perhaps the symbol between the paper dimensions is causing problems. Separately, `\SweaveOpts` does not have to be after `\begin{document}`; I usually put it before `\documentclass`

Comment: Thanks Brian. Indeed, replacing `x` by `,` solves the `NA` issue. Still, it shouldn't matter that a comment changes something (I guess)

Comment: I believe that is an encoding problem. You have to tell Sweave the encoding of your document, since you used a non-ASCII character `×`. You should open R and report `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: You are right. Although I thought I typed the standard letter "x", apparently it indeed used the non-ASCII character "times". `sessionInfo()` shows: `R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)`, `Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0/x86_64 (64-bit)`, `locale: C` (the rest is probably not interesting). How can I tell Sweave about the encoding of the file so that such a problem can be avoided?

Comment: Running `sessionInfo()` from `R.app` gives me `locale: C/en_US.UTF-8/C/C/C/C`... I found precisely this problem on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509395/sweave-doesnt-seem-to-get-rnw-file-encoding-right Still, I don't know how to tell Sweave that the encoding is UTF-8

Comment: Please see my **UPDATE** above. I tried to tell Sweave to use UTF-8, but it does not seem to have any influence on the problem.

Comment: Okay, I did some more experiments and posted the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497621/emacs-r-sweave-utf-8-encoding-is-not-recognized-when-launching-sweave-through