# Emacs, R, Sweave: UTF-8 encoding is not recognized when launching Sweave through Emacs

Tags: r, emacs, sweave

I work with Emacs 24 on Mac OS X 10.7.3 with R 2.14.0. I have a file `foo.Rnw` containing

```
\documentclass[
paper=a4,% 210mm × 297mm
pagesize% write page size to dvi
]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\SweaveOpts{engine=R}
\SweaveOpts{pdf=TRUE}

\begin{document}
Some text
<<>>=
sessionInfo()
@
\end{document}
```

My `.emacs` for working with Sweave looks like this:

```
(add-hook 'Rnw-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
         '("Sweave" "R CMD Sweave %s"
           TeX-run-command nil t :help "Run Sweave") t)
    (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
         '("Stangle" "R CMD Stangle %s"
           TeX-run-command nil t :help "Run Stangle") t)
    (setq TeX-command-default "Sweave")))
```

If I use `C-c C-c` and then choose `Sweave`, the `.tex` file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[
NA
pagesize% write page size to dvi
]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}




\usepackage{Sweave}
\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{Schunk}
\begin{Sinput}
> sessionInfo()
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
R version 2.14.0 (2011-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin11.2.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.14.0
\end{Soutput}
\end{Schunk}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the second line of foo.Rnw containing the non-ASCII character `×` is replaced by `NA`. I could figure out that this has to do with the localization in which `R` runs (see also the output of `locale: [1] C`. I could include statements of the form `export LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"` in my `.bashrc` so that `R` gets the correct `locale`. I can also perfectly use `R CMD Sweave foo.Rnw` *from the terminal* (which of course loads `.bashrc` and thus sets `locale` correctly). The question is: How can I make it work through Emacs, so that I can run Sweave via `C-c C-c Sweave`? I know that Emacs is not aware of variables set in `.bashrc` , but how can I guarantee that `R CMD Sweave` issued from Emacs runs with the same localization as when I execute it from the terminal?

I found several posts to this problem, but no solution for Macs and from within Emacs. Again, note that I can perfectly run `R CMD Sweave foo.Rnw` from the terminal (due to my settings in `.bashrc`) -- most of the posts address this issue -- it's just not working from within Emacs (which is quite annoying).

**UPDATE:**

My `~/.bashrc` contains:

```
export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Following the advice of Yihui, I put in the following in my `~/.Rprofile`:

```
invisible(Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "en_US.UTF-8"))
invisible(Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_US.UTF-8"))
invisible(Sys.setlocale("LC_MONETARY", "en_US.UTF-8"))
invisible(Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8"))
invisible(Sys.setlocale("LC_MESSAGES", "en_US.UTF-8"))
```

This solved the problem.

Comment: If you are very sure all your documents are encoded in UTF8, you can use `Sys.setlocale()` in your `~/.Rprofile` (I do not quite recommend this, though). Encoding problems are tricky. I'm wondering how my knitr package performs in this case (I do not have a Mac so I cannot tell).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Yihui. As you can see from my **UPDATE** above, this solved the problem.

Comment: @MariusHofert: even though it is solved now: does `Sweave ("foo.Rnw", encoding = "utf8")` help?

Comment: @MariusHofert: would you mind answering your own question so it gets out of the "unanswered questions" list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final answer can be found under **UPDATE**.

@cbeleites: I do not run Mac OS X anymore (neither R 2-14) so I can't tell.